# Highcharts - Is it possible to shrink image line?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to shrink image line in pie chart?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/1bwtyo7x/

This not work in pie chart

```
xAxis: {
    tickLength: 2
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan Java, What is the exact problem? Please check the `distance` property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [distance](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance) property of piechart datalabels. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-distance/) JSFiddle for a demo.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    ...
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                distance: '-30%'
            }
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks, it worked!

Comment: That's great @IvanJava. Please accept this as an answer by clicking on the tick mark.